# To align two divs side by side

Tags: html, alignment, footer

I've been trying to align these two divs side by side but they just won't and the font color doesn't seem to change as well. I think it must be some small typo I've missed but I just can't seem to locate it.

Here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/X2Ljp/

```
<div id="footer">
<div id="footer1">
  <p><a href= "Linkpage.html">Site map </a></p>
</div>
<div class="footer2">
  Date updated: 11th May 2014
</div>
```

The CSS

```
#footer
{
clear: both;
background-color: #0193B7;
padding-top: 0px;
border-top-color: black;
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-width: 5px;
}  

.footer2
{
float:left;
width: 20px;
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: what's the width of your footer1 div

Answer (score 0):

From [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp):

> The elements after the floating element will flow around it.
>
> The elements before the floating element will not be affected.

So put your `footer2` div before `footer1` and everything should be fine.

```
<div id="footer">
  <div class="footer2">
    Date updated: 11th May 2014
  </div>
  <div id="footer1">
    <p><a href= "Linkpage.html">Site map </a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't seem to be complete. Did you want something like this?
You need a width in your first div container for the other div's:

```
<div id="footer">
    <div class="footer1">
      <p><a href= "Linkpage.html">Site map</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="footer2">
        <p>Date updated: 11th May 2014</p>
    </div>
</div>

#footer{
  clear: both;
  background-color: #0193B7;
  padding-top: 0px;
  border-top-color: black;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 5px;
  width: 100%
}  

.footer1{
  float:left;
  width: 50%;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
    background-color: blue;
}

.footer2{
  float:right;
  width: 50%;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
    background-color: green;
}
```

[Link to Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X2Ljp/5/)

Comment: @user3622464 Do not forget to check the accept the answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

i guess you want to align side by side footer1 and footer2 so add this code in your css file

```
#footer1 {
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
}
.footer2 {
 display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
}
```

it is more simpler than the use of float and clear